# Get a UserPasswordEncoder Instance in Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, security

I did a user security system without FOSUserBundle and now I'm trying to place the oldUser entity in the newUser entity that implement a user interface.

For do that i have to encode the password like in the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/password_encoding.html) inside the entity

But I can't get an instance of UserPasswordEncoder

When I try to get it from the autowiring symfony4 tell me

*Controller "App\Controller\SecurityController::login()" requires that you provide a value for the "$passwordEncoder" argument. Either the argument is nullable and no null value has been provided, no default value has been provided or because there is a non optional argument after this one.*

So I tried to do a new UserPasswordEncoder() (just for try)

*Type error: Too few arguments to function Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoder::__construct(), 0 passed in /home/connexio/dev/project/src/Controller/SecurityController.php on line 87 and exactly 1 expected*

I also tried **bin/console debug:container --show-private | grep -i Password**

> Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface                                                                 alias for "security.user_password_encoder.generic"
>       security.authentication.listener.form
>    Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener
>     security.authentication.listener.form.main                                                                                           Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener
>     security.authentication.listener.json                                                                                                Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\UsernamePasswordJsonAuthenticationListener
>     security.command.user_password_encoder                                                                                               Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Command\UserPasswordEncoderCommand
>     security.password_encoder                                                                                                            alias for "security.user_password_encoder.generic"
>     security.user_password_encoder.generic                                                                                               **Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoder
>
>     security.validator.user_password**                                                                                                     Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Validator\Constraints\UserPasswordValidator

And this is where I want to invoke the instance

```
/**
 * @Route("/login", name="security_login")
 */
public function login(AuthenticationUtils $helper, UserPasswordEncoder $passwordEncoder): Response
{
    $this->addUsersToUser($passwordEncoder);
    return $this->render('login.html.twig', [....
```

Someone know how to get an instance of UserPasswordEncoder ?

Thank's !

Comment: Type hint against Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface should work as long as you only have one encoder.  Note the Interface suffix.  Otherwise use: "bin/console debug:container --show-private | grep -i Password" to see the available encoders.

Comment: I edited, but what does it means ? I should be able to use it no ?

Comment: Is your SecurityController::login a request action method or just a method you are calling from somewhere else?  I don't understand why you are not using the built in form_login support for logging in.  I understand having to encode a password when registering a user but the SecirityBundle takes care of login chores.

Comment: It's a route call when i want to login , I just wanted to call my addUserInDatabase() from somewhere (at the moment I call it from SecurityController::login), so i did it from a route based method to get the parameter from the autowiring system. But I will edit for show you the short code if it can help ^^

Comment: Sorry.  Still don't understand why you are fooling around with the encoder inside of GET /login.  But even what you showed is missing the Interface suffix.  Might need to spend some time with the autowire docs to see why it is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UserPasswordEncoderInterface instead of UserPasswordEncoder worked and encode as well....